# Sending events between participants on an active twilio video call

Tags: ios, twilio

We are experimenting with the Twilio video call SDK for iOS and we are able to establish a call between two users but now we would like to send events from one user to another. For example, one user would tap a button on his device and the event would be sent to the other device to display a sound or animation. Basically we are looking for a way to establish a data channel between both callers that we can use to send events, much like a websocket.

Thanks for your input! Regards,

Enrique

Answer (score 1):

Twilio recently announced a State Syncronisation API which you can use to solve your problem , have a look : https://www.twilio.com/sync

For your case, you could setup up a "Map" item ( a map of event to device identity ) on Twilio sync which could be used by a device to push their events to Cloud to which any subscribed devices can get the info pushed to .

Comment: Interesting, sounds like a similar offering as Google's Firebase. I guess this could work but what I really wanted was using the same video api's to send simple messages and not having to add a whole new SDK for this simple task. I mean, there is already a connection between both ends so it is a matter of opening a new channel between both parties over the same connection. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Truely said . In my opinion (purely my view) its more about modularity - microservices  . A Video SDK should handle tasks , functions and actions associated for that function .  Syncing state or pub/sub to events is not an intrinsic functionality of the video SDK , so it might be a good idea to keep it in a separate SDK ( which can be used for similar use cases on other products too )

Comment: Totally agree with you in terms of the modularity and intrinsic functionality of the video SDK. I think I have an idea on how to accomplish this using the conversation and participants id as keys to create a channel between devices and send data using either the sync api or Firebase. I'm now evaluating options. Thanks again for the input!

Comment: Cool..All the best. Would love to hear back from you on the logic and flow , once you progress ahead with this .Cheers!